# can someone explain behavior for the given loop?

Tags: c, for-loop

```
for (k=0; tmp[j+k]=next[k]; k++);
```

when is this for-loop going to end and why?

Is it going to end when next[k] == 0 or when tmp[j+k] == 0?
or is there something else that I am missing?

sorry for my bad eng. and sorry for noob question.

Comment: It's going to end when `next[k]` evaluates to 0

Comment: Given that the condition is an assignment; I'm not sure that this will ever end.

Comment: Yes, that someone is called a *debugger* : Compile with `gcc -Wall -g` and use `gdb` to run step by step your program.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Notice that the loop has no body. The work is done in the end test. The end test is implicit, because although it assigns the value of `next[k]` to `tmp[j+k]`, the *expression* also holds the value and is either 0 (false) or non-0 (true).

So the loop ends when 0 has been copied from one array to the other.

Comment: Thank you sir, and sorry for wasting your time, this was for my school and I dont know how to use debugger in Code Blocks yet.

Comment: I cant like yet cause im lacking reputation but you were first to answer it and I accepted it. Thanks again.

Comment: "I dont know how to use debugger in Code Blocks yet." - press F7

Comment: Facebook is infecting our community.  Did the op really just say "like" in place of upvoting?

Answer (score 0):

It will end when the value of the expression `tmp[j+k]=next[k]` evaluates to zero. It so happens that the value of this expression is also the value of its right hand side: the value of `next[k]`.

Answer (score 0):

The loop will continue until the value of the expression `tmp[j+] = next[k]` evaluates to `0`. That will have happen when `next[k]` evaluates to `0`.

If you are writing this code, or you are responsible for maintaining it, please make it more readable.

Use something along the lines of:

```
int valueToStopAt = 0;
for (k=0; (tmp[j+k]=next[k]) != valueToStopAt ; k++);
```